# Drupal element classes

Tags: php, css, class, templates, drupal

I'm using Drupal 7, Commerce Kickstarter project, with my own theme. I'm trying to theme the whole thing which is proving difficult since my nodes (products) won't show CSS classes on node element (node template). It just shows

```
<article>
```

even though my node.tpl.php has:

```
<article<?php print $attributes; ?>>
```

I copied some stuff from the Commerce Alpha theme, which uses the **theme_preprocess()** function, but it has one problem: it creates duplicate 'class' attribute entries on various HTML elements

```
<body class="classes" class="classes">
```

but on the other hand it does create these missing class definitions for the

```
<article>
```

which turns into

```
<article class="node node-product node-product-type node-product node-product-type-full nodeproduct-full">
```

**How can alter this so I can get these classes to print out in my HTML without having duplicate class attribute?**

```
<?php
function theme_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
    $vars['attributes_array']['class'] = $vars['classes_array'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"theme_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)" function is called at any templating levels (html, page, nodes ...). You can only apply the classes you want by filtering with the "$hook" variable or use another preprrocess function. Since it seems you want to add classes at the node template level, you could use the "template_preprocess_node" function ; for instance (replace "yourtheme" with the name of your theme):

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'my-class';
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'another-class';
}
```

You can get those classes in your node template in the "$classes_array" or in the flattened (by the core) "$classes" variable ; example :

```
<article class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

> "theme_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)" function is called at any templating
>   levels (html, page, nodes ...). You can only apply the classes you
>   want by filtering with the "$hook" variable or use another preprrocess
>   function. Since it seems you want to add classes at the node template
>   level, you could use the "template_preprocess_node" function ; for
>   instance (replace "yourtheme" with the name of your theme):
>
> function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
>   $variables['classes_array'][] = 'my-class';
>   $variables['classes_array'][] = 'another-class'; }
>
> You can get those classes in your node template in the
>   "$classes_array" or in the flattened (by the core) "$classes" variable
>   ; example :
>
> ">

Actually, this did not work. I don't know why, maybe because it's a product type, not a real node type... Anyway. I came up with an alternate solution. This problem only presented itself in the body element, and block classes. So what I did was, I took those templates and overwrited them in the /templates folder and removed the

```
class="<?php print $classes; ?>"
```

Now, with leaving the

```
<?php print $attributes; ?>
```

intact, the function beforehand creates these missing classes. What's funny is that it creates them for the product nodes too which DOES NOT have $attributes in it's template, so I'm starting to wonder where does it take the template from.. I'm gonna be hashing through the modules of Commerce to find this out. So maybe your answer was the solution but the template is somewhere in the modules and I need to put it in the theme too. Thanks!

Comment: So yeah, the template file was referenced from the profiles\commerce_kickstart\modules\commerce_kickstart\commerce_kickstart_product_ui\theme folder, node--product--type.tpl.php and I copied this to my theme and just tweaked it a bit. It isn't nescessary to do the preprocess function if I add the print $classes to the template now, but for future reference if someone is looking for this, they know.